# how to set icons and theme from terminal?

Tags: bash, themes

Is there a way to set active icon theme and GTK theme from a terminal?

I would like to write a script that installs and sets everything up the way i like it on a fresh install.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Should work with gsettings try these commands...

Change GTK-Theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "CoolestThemeOnEarth"
```

Change Icon-Theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'MyIconTheme'
```

Change Window-Theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "CoolestThemeOnEarth"
```

Comment: Aah should have thought about that, thank you. btw do you know the difference between gconftool-2 and gsettings?

Comment: You´re welcome :-)
GConf is obsolete. It is the older GNOME 2.x configuration API and system, and has been replaced by DConf/GSettings in newer versions. However, some applications still use it.

GSettings is a GLib implementation of DConf, which stores its data in a binary database.

The gsettings command line tool is simply a tool to access or modify settings via the GSettings API, in the same way that the older gconftool command line tool is for GConf.

Comment: Howto get the options available from each property?

Comment: Does this work on other desktop enviromnents?

Comment: Some applications still use older GConf so this answer is incomplete, because these older applications are not affected by `gsettings` commands at all. If you want to post a complete answer, you would have to add `gconftool-2` alternatives for your `gsettings` command?